# cascade delete all virtual collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using MVC3 to build a web application. In this application I have an entity which has x number of virtual collections which themselves could hold y number of virtual collections.

Is there a way in which I can "simulate" a cascade delete such that when I delete the top entity, it first tries to delete the child collection entities recursively.

I know I could do it with the database cascading options (and a couple of triggers) but I would really like to know if this is possible in C#.

EDIT:
Top entity:

```
public class Tournament {
    public int TournamentID { get; set; }
    // other properties
    public virtual ICollection<Official> Officials { get; set; }
}
```

Child:

```
public class Official {
    public int OfficialID { get; set; }
    // other properties
    public virtual ICollection<Matches> Matches { get; set; }
}
```

So when I delete a `Tournament` entity, it should also delete the `Officials` and in the `Officials` it should delete the `Matches`

Comment: Show the definition of at least one Parent/Child pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure the association from child to parent does not allow nulls.

Then Delete the parent.